# Where can I find API documentation for Windows Mobile phone application skin?

Tags: c++, c, windows-mobile

I have to customize the look of Windows Mobile (5/6) dialer application. From bits and pieces of information and the actual custom skin implementations in the wild I know that it is actually possible to change a great deal. I am looking for ways to change the look and feel of the following screens:

- Actual dialer (buttons, number display, etc.)
- Incoming call notification
- Outgoing call screen
- In-call screen

At least in the HTC Fuze device there is a custom skin that can be enabled or disabled, and it is actually a dll.

Can anyone point me to a section in MSDN, any kind of sample code, or at least mention the keyword I should be looking for?

Edit: There seem to be a number of "skins" for download. How do they do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no API for the default phone dailer and you can't replace it.  The only people that can are the OEM's that make the devices.

I beleave you can add a context menu extender but I can't find the sample but that's about it.

As the other post article link goes into, there are enough API's in WM that you can write your own dailer and kind of replace it in most cases.  Altho you can detect incomming calls you may be out of luck displaying a GUI in all situations (e.g. when the phone is locked).

Answer (score 0):

There is an [article](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Architecture/Creating-custom-Phone-App-Windows-Mobile/) series by Jeff Cogswell which could be very interesting for you.